# Incomplete sitecore publish ( presentation details missing )

Tags: sitecore, publish

When i publish items in sitecore ( Sitecore 8 Update 2 ) i noticed that the presentation details aren't being published. At first this didn't happen a lot but now it's becoming a real problem.

I used to have a fallback plan where i would fully delete the items in the web database and then a publish would work fine. But now even when i delete the items from the web database only the item itself is published. There is no error or message.

( I just tried to add the presentation details to the web item itself, saved it and looked at it again. But the new presentation details were gone )

Does anyone know what could cause this ?

Comment: When publishing, are you publishing (and viewing) the language with the changes to presentation details on?

Comment: Yes. I do have multiple languages but i've been working only with english items.

Comment: So you are making changes to the versioned layouts, i.e. presentation details in 'en' and viewing the site in the language 'en'

Comment: Are the related templates and standard values published? Can you force through a publish with the republish option?

Comment: I can't actually view the site anymore as most top items no longer have presentation details. But i'm always working/looking in english

The templates seem to be fine, they haven't changed ( not by me or otherwise ). Republish and smart publish have the same effect/problem

Comment: Is anything detailed in the logs when trying to view these pages with no presentation? On Presentation Details, what is displayed when you click the Final Layout tab?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the exact same problem and it turned out to be due to the renderings (and the containing folder) used by the page having been created in the wrong language.

If you try to a) publish in all available languages, or b) ensure that your rendering definition items (and all ancestors) are in the correct language, this could fix your issue.